# Intercepting other apps push notifications on iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, bluetooth, apple-push-notifications

I need to intercept the following push notifications from my application:

- SMS / iMessage
- WhatsApp
- Telegram

I will be sending those directly to show on an external device display via Bluetooth.

I see Pebble are doing this:
https://help.getpebble.com/customer/portal/articles/1191239-setting-up-ios-notifications

Is this accomplishable? or Apple's sandbox policy prevents me?
If Apple are the problem, how does Pebble handle this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look at [ANCS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html).

"The purpose of the Apple Notification Center Service (ANCS) is to give Bluetooth accessories (that connect to iOS devices through a Bluetooth low-energy link) a simple and convenient way to access many kinds of notifications that are generated on iOS devices".

I presume this would require custom code to be written on the Bluetooth device, so it depends what you have access to. But as far as I'm aware, this would be the only way to send notifications for apps other than your own to be sent to a connected Bluetooth device.